# D3 stack layout issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm having trouble with dynamically adding data to a stack graph. Check out these examples.

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/dL5t9c0n/8/

The stack graph is initialized with the data, 2 stacks.

Not working: https://jsfiddle.net/fsne8jrL/6/

Press the button to append layers.

I try to append data to the graph after it's been initialized. The first stack appends fine. However the second stack goes crazy. The y0 values for the second layer look fine. It looks like the second layer is pushing the x axis way down.

I'm pretty sure it's because i'm doing the data join wrong, but i can't figure out why.

Here's the data join code for the non-working fiddle.

```
var updateData = d3.select(".parts-comparison-graph").selectAll("path")
                  .data(stack(layers));
                console.log(updateData);
                updateData.transition()
                  .duration(2500)
                  .attr("d", function(d){return area(d.values)})
                  .each("end",function(){svg.attr('pointer-events', 'auto')});
                updateData.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this for loop this will generate as many paths as the test data length.

In your case you were just making a single path...

```
var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
            var zeroLayer = [];
            for (var j =0; j < test.length; j++){
               var zeroSegment = {};
              zeroSegment.values = [];
              for(var i=2000;i<=currentYear;i++){
                  zeroSegment.values.push({"x":new Date(i,0,1),"y":0,"y0":0});
              }
              zeroLayer.push(zeroSegment);//only one path gets inserted
            }
```

In the corrected code test data has 6 data so 6 zeroLayers be created.

```
for (var j =0; j < test.length; j++){
               var zeroSegment = {};
              zeroSegment.values = [];
              for(var i=2000;i<=currentYear;i++){
                  zeroSegment.values.push({"x":new Date(i,0,1),"y":0,"y0":0});
              }
              zeroLayer.push(zeroSegment);//test data has 6 data so 6 zeroLayers be created
            }
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9e0uaqb3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: One question, what if you didn't know the length of test data? Like the user could choose to only add 3 layers, or 7 layers, and i wouldn't know this in advance.

Comment: at any time when you know that you need a new layer you will need to add a path like you doing here _svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(stack(zeroLayer))
              .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", function(d){return area(d.values)});_